# Group items based on Month and year along with date range and type filters in Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I need to group following JSON data based on Month and year(stTransactionDate)

`[{"stTransactionDate":"2017-03-08","stTransactioTime":"12:29:14.96","stTransactioType":"FS","stRequestAmount":"12.00","stCompletionAmount":"12.00","sFee":"00.20","stDepositAmount":"12.00","stTransactioDesc":"Balance Enquiry"},{"stTransactionDate":"2017-08-03","stTransactioTime":"12:29:14.96","stTransactioType":"CA","stRequestAmount":"12.00","stCompletionAmount":"12.00","sFee":"00.20","stDepositAmount":"12.00","stTransactioDesc":"ATM Transaction"},{"stTransactionDate":"2017-03-11","stTransactioTime":"12:39:14.96","stTransactioType":"FS","stRequestAmount":"12.00","stCompletionAmount":"12.00","sFee":"00.20","stDepositAmount":"12.00","stTransactioDesc":"Balance Enquiry"},{"stTransactionDate":"2017-03-11","stTransactioTime":"12:39:14.96","stTransactioType":"CA","stRequestAmount":"12.00","stCompletionAmount":"12.00","sFee":"00.20","stDepositAmount":"12.00","stTransactioDesc":"Balance Enquiry"},{"stTransactionDate":"2017-03-08","stTransactioTime":"12:29:14.96","stTransactioType":"CA","stRequestAmount":"12.00","stCompletionAmount":"12.00","sFee":"00.20","stDepositAmount":"12.00","stTransactioDesc":"Balance Enquiry"},{"stTransactionDate":"2016-03-08","stTransactioTime":"12:29:14.96","stTransactioType":"CA","stRequestAmount":"12.00","stCompletionAmount":"12.00","sFee":"00.20","stDepositAmount":"12.00","stTransactioDesc":"Balance Enquiry"}]`

I tried using customized pipe but iam getting errors. Along with that i have to apply filters like need to show only FS,CA(stTransactioType) and date range filters}(i.e, start date and end date).

Anyone please help me with this...

I used the following pipe code

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({name: "filter",pure: false})
   export class ArrayFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: Array<any>, conditions: {[field: string]: any}): Array<any> {
        return items.filter(item => {
            for (let field in conditions) {
                if (item[field].split('-')[1] !== conditions[field].split('-')[1] || item[field].split('-')[0] !== conditions[field].split('-')[0]  ) {

                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

and in html 
`<ion-card reorder="true" ion-item *ngFor="let item of items1  | filter:{stTransactionDate:item.stTransactionDate} >`

I am getting error at passing item.stTransactionDate to filter

Comment: Can you share any of the code your code?

Comment: @Kyrsberg added the code please take a look

Comment: format your codes correctly

Comment: @ IsuruAb Sorry I posted first time in this site, formatted the code please check and give me suggestions

Comment: Any idea how to do it using pipes?